# getting while trying to parse page with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

When i'm trying to get all page content i'm getting this error in console

```
  2018-11-08 20:55:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-11-08 20:55:34 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-11-08 20:55:34 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-11-08 20:55:34 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 127, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 83, in start_requests
    yield Request(url, dont_filter=True)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 62, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
```

This is how my code look like

```
import scrapy

class Shopee(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'Shopee'
    start_urls = ['http://www.shopee.sg/Games-Hobbies-cat.14']


    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.text)
```

Comment: The error seems correct - according to isitup.org, the site is down: https://isitup.org/www.clearshopee.sg

Comment: Yeah, the URL is down. That is why.

Comment: i'm sorry i corrected link and updated error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message in your post is related to a missing `http(s)://` in the `start_urls`. I suppose you forgot to update the error message when you updated the code.

But after running your code, it seems this site is blocking clients based on the `User-Agent`. Consider trying a browser's user-agent string. Eg:

```
name = 'Shopee'
start_urls = ['http://www.shopee.sg/Games-Hobbies-cat.14']
custom_settings = {
    'DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS': {
        'User-Agent': (
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14'
            ' (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A'
        )
    }
}
```